# Based on the code below I make changes to the "s.txt" file.Is there a way to do this for every txt file in the folder regardless of the file name?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim sBuf As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sFileName As String

' Edit as needed
sFileName = "M:\s.txt"

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

sTemp = Replace(sTemp, ",", ".")

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, sTemp
Close iFileNum

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Apply to All Files in a Folder

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessFolder()

    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test"
    Const FilePattern As String = "*.txt"
    
    ' Make sure the folder path ends with the path separator.
    Dim sPath As String: sPath = FolderPath
    If Right(sPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        sPath = sPath & Application.PathSeparator
    End If
    
    ' Write the first file name to a variable ('sName').
    Dim sName As String: sName = Dir(sPath & FilePattern)
    
    ' Validate the first file name.
    If Len(sName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    Dim tfCount As Long ' total
    Dim pfCount As Long ' processed
    
    ' Process each file using the 'ReplaceCommasWithDots' procedure.
    Do While Len(sName) > 0
        tfCount = tfCount + 1
        FilePath = sPath & sName
        On Error Resume Next
            ReplaceCommasWithDots FilePath
            ErrNum = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ErrNum > 0 Then ErrNum = 0 Else pfCount = pfCount + 1
        sName = Dir
    Loop

    ' Inform (with stats).
    MsgBox "Files processed: " & pfCount & "(" & tfCount & ")", vbInformation

End Sub

Sub ReplaceCommasWithDots(ByVal FilePath As String)

    Dim TextFile As Long: TextFile = FreeFile
    
    Dim TextString As String
    
    Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
        TextString = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
    Close TextFile
    
    TextString = Replace(TextString, ",", ".")
    
    Open FilePath For Output As TextFile
        Print #TextFile, TextString
    Close TextFile

End Sub
```

Comment: I noticed that when converting the txt file to excel, the date format is lost in 2 columns A & L in the xlsx file, with the result that the date 01/03/2020, which is correct, appears in the xlsx file as 03 /01/2020. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted code. It uses `Dir` to find all 'txt' files in the defined folder path:

```
Sub Macro3_AllTxtFiles()
 Dim sBuf As String, sTemp As String, iFileNum As Integer, sFileName As String
 Dim folderPath As String

 folderPath = "M:\"

 sFileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.txt") 'first text file name (without the folder path...)

 Do While sFileName <> ""
        sTemp = "" 'initialize the variable for each iteration
        iFileNum = FreeFile
        Open folderPath & sFileName For Input As iFileNum
                Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
                    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
                    sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
                Loop
        Close iFileNum
        
        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, ",", ".")
        
        iFileNum = FreeFile
        Open folderPath & sFileName For Output As iFileNum
            Print #iFileNum, sTemp
        Close iFileNum
        
        sFileName = Dir
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I noticed that when converting the txt file to excel, the date format is lost in 2 columns A & L in the xlsx file, with the result that the date 01/03/2020, which is correct, appears in the xlsx file as 03 /01/2020. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Dionysis Mitropoulos This has nothing to do with the code I supplied. The Date from the text file is in a different format against your system one. Since you chose a not relevant date, having day and month less than 12 I cannot deduce which is which. It probably load the `Date` field as string when what to be month is bigger then 12. I have a solution for such a case, but this does not make the object of my answer, which looked to not like it, anymore...

Comment: @Dionysis Mitropoulos No need to mark my answer as accepted! Please, mark the one you liked better!